# Why is NextPermutation slow?

Tags: performance-tuning, permutation

```
<< Combinatorica`
Permutations[Range[0, 9]][[1000000]] // AbsoluteTiming
Nest[NextPermutation, Range[0, 9], 1*^6 - 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I want to save memory, so I tried `NextPermutation` ,but it's kind of slow, why?

[image]

Comment: If you look in the documentation tp `Nest`, then you understand the iteration is executed 999999 times.

Comment: Rather than repeatedly using `NextPermutation`, you could use [`PermutationFromIndex`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PermutationFromIndex) to get the 999999+1th lexicographic permutation straight away and very quickly. `ResourceFunction["PermutationFromIndex"][10^6, 10] - 1` gives `{2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 1, 5, 4, 6, 0}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need [UnrankPermutation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/UnrankPermutation.html)

```
<< Combinatorica`;
UnrankPermutation[10^6 - 1, Range[0, 9]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0001106, {2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 1, 5, 4, 6, 0}}

I wrote a `takePermutation` function, maybe you are interested

```
Quiet[<< Combinatorica`];

Clear[cf, takePermutation];
cf = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}, {num, _Integer}},
   Module[{res = l, n = Length @ l, i, j, nl, tmp},
    Table[
     nl = res;
     i = n - 1;
     While[nl[[i]] > nl[[i + 1]], i--];
     j = n;
     While[nl[[j]] < nl[[i]], j--];
     tmp = nl[[i]];
     nl[[i]] = nl[[j]];
     nl[[j]] = tmp;
     res = nl[[Join[Range[i], Range[n, i + 1, -1]]]]
     , {num}]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

takePermutation[l_?VectorQ, i1_Integer, i2_Integer] := 
  If[i1 == 1, Join[{l}, cf[UnrankPermutation[i1 - 1, l], i2 - i1]], 
    cf[UnrankPermutation[i1 - 2, l], i2 - i1 + 1]] /; 0 < i1 <= i2;

r1 = takePermutation[Range[11], 11! - 10^5, 11!]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Take[Permutations[Range[11]], {11! - 10^5, 11!}]; // AbsoluteTiming
r1 == r2
```

> {0.0396038, Null}
> {0.777691, Null}
> True

Comment: It is a great answer.