# Finding the first few permutations of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Given a list, possibly with repeated elements, I am trying to get a list that consists of a specified number of distinct permutations of the list. Essentially, I want to something that works like `Take[Permutations[mylist],100]` which gives the first 100 permutations of `mylist`. The issue is that this code first computes `Permutations[mylist]` and then takes the first 100 elements, which is a waste of time and memory space, and will throw errors if mylist is too large.

Essentially, I want something that gives the same output as `Take[Permutations[mylist],100]` but runs more efficiently.

This seems like a very basic problem but I can't figure out how to implement it. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: This may be useful, [why-is-nextpermutation-slow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230193/why-is-nextpermutation-slow/230211#230211)

Comment: An example of a list with repeated elements would be handy to compare the timing of the solutions you'll get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd want anything but a random sample from the list of possible distinct permutations so I don't see that `NextPermutation` or `UnrankPermutation` in the `Combinatorica` package would be useful to generate 100 permutations in lexicographic or some other "fixed" order.

If the length of `mylist` is more than 10 and is full of distinct elements, then just taking a `RandomSample` 100 times is probably all you need.  If there is some chance of duplicates, you could over-sample (i.e., more than 100 times) and just delete the duplicates.

```
mylist = Range[10];
x = (Table[RandomSample[mylist, Length[mylist]], {i, 2*100}] // DeleteDuplicates)[[1 ;; 100]];
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks for the answer!